# For loop slows down

Tags: c++, for-loop, optimization

I'm writing a program that loops through a vector of documents (specific type, pointed by m_docs). Each doc has an attribute which is a vector of ~17000 zeros that are changed on some occasions (the point of the loop). I have ~3200 docs. My problem is that the first hundred docs are processed rather quickly, and then it really slows down. I would like to understand why it slows down, and to know how I could fix it (or at least optimize it)

Portion of code in question:

```
for (int k = 0; k < m_docs->size(); k++) {
    int pos;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > >::iterator it = m_index.begin();
    std::map<string,int> cleanList = (*m_docs)[k].getCleantList();
    for (auto const& p : cleanList) {
        pos = distance(it, m_index.find(p.first));
        float weight = computeIdf(p.first) * computeTf(p.first, (*m_docs)[k]);
        (*m_docs)[k].setCoord(pos, weight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Before doing anything else, are you running an optimized build or a "debug", non-optimized build?

Comment: Sounds like you could be running out of main memory, and now you're paging memory to/from disk.

Comment: That `it` definition is like a textbook use case for `auto`...

Comment: At some point, you may be re-using dynamic memory, rather than fetching new blocks from the memory pool.  If dynamic memory is fragmented, your program will slow down.

Comment: You're making *lots* of copies. You are using `(*m_docs)[k]` a lot. (And what is `(*m_docs)[k]`?) You are doing lots of searching a in a hash table. You haven't shown is the functions `computeIdf` or `computeTf`. Have you done any performance testing to see where your code is bogging down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This could be more efficient:

   ```
   std::map<string,int> cleanList
   ```

   into

   ```
   std::map<string,int> const& cleanList
   ```

   Worst case, `getCleantList` already made the copy, and you get a temp bound to a const& (which is fine). But way more likely, you decimate memory allocations because you're no longer copying maps containing strings
2. Also, look at the efficiency of the search here:

   ```
   pos = distance(it, m_index.find(p.first));
   ```

   You *called* the variable `m_index`. You might need to improve locality (flat_map) or use a hash based container (unordered_map e.g.)

Review your data structures (at the very least for the `m_index`)