# .net large for loop slowing down

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have a large for-loop (30k max iterations) that seems to be consistently slowing down:

- The first thousand iterations take 1.34s
- After 12k iterations, the next thousand take 5.31s
- After 23k iterations, the next thousand take 6.65s
- The last thousand iterations take 7.43s

In order to gain a little performance i switched from a `foreach` loop to a `for` loop, and tried release configuration, but I can't find anything else in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808702/for-loop-slows-down) that applies to me.  The loop is in an async method

Why does the loop slow down?  Can it be avoided?

```
for(int iter = 0; iter < LargeList1.Count; iter++)
{
    var cl_from = LargeList1[iter];
    if(LargeList2.Any(cl => cl.str.Contains(cl_from.str)))
    {
        DateTime dt1 = //last write time of a file
        DateTime dt2 = //last write time of a different file
        if(DateTime.Compare(dt1, dt2) > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                CopyFile(//Kernel32 CopyFile a file overwrite);
                globals.fileX++;
            }
            catch(Exception filexx)
            {
                //error handler
            }
        }
        else
        {
            globals.fileS++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(//create a directory, no check if it already exists);
        try
        {
            CopyFile(//Kernel32 CopyFile a file do not overwrite);
            globals.fileX++;
        }
        catch(Exception filex)
        {
            // error handler
        }

    }
    gui.UpdateCount(globals.fileF, globals.fileX, globals.fileS); //updates iteration on textboxes
    float p = (float)100.0*((float)globals.fileF + (float)globals.fileX + (float)globals.fileS)/(float)globals.totalCount;
    gui.setProgress(p); //updates progressbar
}
```

Edit: as many suggested, Using hashset.Contains(cl_from.str) solved the problem.

Comment: What does `iterations n-m take x` mean? Does it mean *anytime there are that many iterations*, or *the first/last c iterations take*?

Comment: iterations 29k-30k take 7.43s means the last 1000 iterations take 7.43 seconds.  I'll update it to clarify

Comment: Is that `7.43s` from the beginning of iterating, or `7.43s` from `iteration 29k` to `iteration 30k`?

Comment: 7.43 from iteration 29k to iteration 30k.  Does the update clarify it?

Comment: Have you considered trying to use a **conditional breakpoint** to evaluate your `for` loop after a given number of iterations? Also, can't you use raw arrays instead of lists? They should be much faster.

Comment: Is anything *growing* as your loop executes? If, for example, LargeList2 is adding elements, it will take progressively more time for `Any` to be evaluated, as that's an embedded loop over that list.

Comment: My assumption is that that part is slow later on `LargeList2.Any(cl => cl.str.Contains(cl_from.str))`. If result will yield quite late from LargeList2 then that will take more time. Maybe you can optimize that matching somehow (e.g. remove elements from list if their match does not repeat, remember an index, use dictionary of already matched items etc.)

Comment: How could conditional breakpoints be used to prevent slowing the loop down?  It is necessary to complete all 30k iterations.  I will look into the raw arrays.

Comment: Your algorithm is actually O(n^2) - for each entry in `LargeList1`, you have to search through `LargeList2` to find a match. If elements at the end of `LargeList1` generally correspond to elements at the end of `LargeList2`, that could explain the slow down. The solution would be to use a dictionary lookup instead (if possible).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram the lists do not grow.

Comment: I like the dictionary idea.  Another suggestion would be to capture the results of the `if` statement in an array.  You may be creating more directories in the later parts of the loop, which would explain the slowdown as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nature of these 2 items, I can imagine would be the bottleneck.

```
for(int iter = 0; iter < LargeList1.Count; iter++)
{
    .....
    if(LargeList2.Any(cl => cl.str.Contains(cl_from.str)))
    ...........
```

You are checking if any word from another large list, is contained within the current string.

A few reasons why it probably is slower over time:

1. Initially its faster because GC doesnt run as much, as you get further in the loop, the GC has to collect more and more often.
2. Length of string `cl_from.st` is possibly getting larger?

Some points to consider:

1. How big is `cl_from.str` and `LargeList2`, is it worth creating a hash of all the possible values in `cl_from.str` and then checking that has lookup or possibly even creating a hash set of all the LargeList2 strings, and then use that, iterating over each combination of string in `cl_From.str`.
2. You probably want to improve your searching algorithm, e.g. check out [C# .NET: FASTEST WAY TO CHECK IF A STRING OCCURS WITHIN A STRING](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-occurs-within-a-string). Or google it for other string search indexing/algorithm. Why not use something like Lucene.NET?
3. Use a .NET profiler to find out where the bottleneck is, and where it is spending time.

Comment: I will try your suggestions.  cl_from.st does not grow during the loop, I'm guessing it's the GC and the contains.

Comment: Using hashset.Contains(cl_from.str) solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is that the file system is causing you trouble. If you have thousands of files in a single folder, opening a file can take a very long time. The system loads the directory and does a sequential search to find the entry for the file you requested.

If you're getting a list of the files in the directory and then opening them one-by-one, it will take an increasingly long time to open a file as you get further into the list. If you have, for example:

```
foreach (var filename in Directory.GetFiles(...))
{
    // start stopwatch
    // open the file
    // stop stopwatch
    // display time
    // close the file
}
```

You'll find that the time to open the file increases as you get further in the list of files. That difference isn't really significant when you're talking about a few hundred files, but it becomes quite evident when you have 10,000 files in a single folder.

The solution is to break things up so that you don't have so many files in a folder. Rather than 10,000 files in a single folder, have 100 folders with 100 files each. Or 10 folders with 1,000 files each. Either is going to be much faster than a single folder with a huge number of files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the offending line will be:

```
if(LargeList2.Any(cl => cl.str.Contains(cl_from.str)))
```

The 'Any' extension method with the lambda expression will ultimately be slower than the longhand version due to the overhead of the anonymous delegate, so you could try expanding out thus:

```
foreach (var cl in LargeList2)
{
    if (cl.str.Contains(cl_from.str))
    {
        // do stuff
        break;
    }
}
```

But I think this iteration is where you might find the slowness creeps in, what with the anonymous delegate and the string function.  Is is likely that the iteration has to work through most of LargeList2 to find a match as the iteration goes on, meaning a slow down in performance as the process goes on.

Try using ANTS performance profiler with line-level timings enabled to see if it shows this line as the hotspot after running this process.

Comment: `Any` basically compiles to that though. The only different is instead of `// do stuff`, it will be `return true;`

Comment: Try a big test in a console app with timing ... for-next loop with a comparison inside vs. enumerator extension method e.g. .Where(x => x.Prop > value) ... the former wins out!